# How to make systemd wait until process started

Tags: systemd

As shown below I am using below configuration where process2 is dependent on process1 to start. Is there a way to block starting process2 until process1 is completely started ? Currently it seems once fork is done on process1, process2 is just started off.

```
cat process2.service
[Unit]
Description=process1
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=process1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/process1 -d
ExecStop=/bin/kill -9 `cat /var/run/process1.pid`
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

cat process2.service
[Unit]
Description=process2
Wants=network-online.target
After=process1.service

[Service]
Type=forking
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=process2
ExecStart=/usr/bin/process2 -d
ExecStop=/bin/kill -9 `cat /var/run/process2.pid`
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: what constitutes process1 being  "completely started" ? Is it your code?

Comment: Instead of `ExecStop` you should be using just `PidFile=/var/run/process2.pid`